# How to get Business Central installation error message from automation API?

Tags: dynamics-business-central, businesscentral

I am working on a deployment Pipeline, which automatically installs extensions into Business Central environments using the BC automation api. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/administration/itpro-introduction-to-automation-apis) Sometimes some of the extensions may fail to be installed, because they contain errors, are older than the currently installed version or multiple installation processes running simultaneously interfere with one another.

How do I get the error reason / code / message from Business Central using an API?

I have not found any way to do this. The automation API only let's me know that an error occurred, but it does not give me an error message.

Though I have found out that I can use the Business Central admin center API to get the operations of my extensions (for example "install") like so:

GET /admin/v2.19/applications/{applicationFamily}/environments/{environmentName}/apps/{appId}/operations

That does not work for all extensions though and only lists successful installation attempts, not failed ones.

How do I get error messages from my failed installations?